# Prune some elements from large xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file of more than 1GB and I want to reduce the size of the file by removing unwanted children of a parent tag by creating a new xml file or rewriting the existing one. How this can be done through python as the file is large,simple parse `tree = ElementTree.parse(xmlfile)` won't work.

[XML file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7YnPsHwbHY8MDhMNi1ZZnRvV2c)

In the file for every parent tag `TasksReportNode` I want to have only the child `TableRow` with `RowCount` attribute with value 0 and reject all other children(Table Row) of that parent.

Sample XML code:

```
<TasksReportNode Name="Task15">
    <TableData NumRows="97" NumColumns="15">
        <TableRow RowCount="0">
            <TableColumn Name="Task"><![CDATA[   Task15 [GET - /PULSEV31/appView/projectFeedHidden.jsp - 200]]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Status"><![CDATA[Success]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Successful"><![CDATA[96]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Failed"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Timedout"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Total"><![CDATA[96]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Min(ms)"><![CDATA[15]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg(ms)"><![CDATA[24.20]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg-90%(ms)"><![CDATA[54.55]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="90%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[89.98]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="95%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[95.24]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="99%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[99.45]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Max(ms)"><![CDATA[94]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Std. Dev."><![CDATA[15.74]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Bytes Recd(KB)"><![CDATA[192]]></TableColumn>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowCount="1">
            <TableColumn Name="Task"><![CDATA[      VirtualUser1]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Status"><![CDATA[Success]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Successful"><![CDATA[1]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Failed"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Timedout"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Total"><![CDATA[1]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Min(ms)"><![CDATA[934]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg(ms)"><![CDATA[934.00]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg-90%(ms)"><![CDATA[950.00]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="90%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[1,000.50]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="95%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[1,000.50]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="99%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[1,000.50]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Max(ms)"><![CDATA[934]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Std. Dev."><![CDATA[0.00]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Bytes Recd(KB)"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
    </TableData>
    <TableData NumRows="1" NumColumns="2">
        <TableRow RowCount="0">
            <TableColumn Name="Response Time Interval (ms)"><![CDATA[0 - 99]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Frequency"><![CDATA[96]]></TableColumn>
        </TableRow>
    </TableData>
</TasksReportNode>
<TasksReportNode Name="Task16">
    <TableData NumRows="97" NumColumns="15">
        <TableRow RowCount="0">
            <TableColumn Name="Task"><![CDATA[   Task16 [GET - /PULSEV31/appView/projectCommentHidden.jsp - 200]]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Status"><![CDATA[Success]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Successful"><![CDATA[96]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Failed"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Timedout"><![CDATA[0]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Total"><![CDATA[96]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Min(ms)"><![CDATA[15]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg(ms)"><![CDATA[22.73]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Avg-90%(ms)"><![CDATA[54.55]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="90%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[90.93]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="95%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[96.25]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="99%ile(ms)"><![CDATA[100.50]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Max(ms)"><![CDATA[109]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Std. Dev."><![CDATA[14.76]]></TableColumn>
            <TableColumn Name="Bytes Recd(KB)"><![CDATA[192]]></TableColumn>
        </TableRow>
    </TableData>
</TasksReportNode>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
xmL = 'F:\\Reports\\Logs\\Result_TG1_V16.xml'

context = etree.iterparse(xmL,  events=("start", "end"),)
for event, element in context:
if element.tag == 'TasksReportNode':
    for child1 in element:
        for child2 in child1:
        if child2.get("RowCount") == "0":
            for child3 in child2:
            print(child3.tag, child3.text)
element.clear() # discard the element
del context
```

Now we have all the `RowCount` with value '0' and that can be added to parent, leaving all other siblings.

Comment: Wondering why this question is being down voted without any comments for reasoning? Is it due to a google drive link? Interested to know

Comment: @TejasPendse Is anything wrong with the question? Should I remove the drive link

Comment: @siddhu619 To me your question seems clear and as you have provided short example of XML in the question, the link to larger file on GDrive is correct. Keep it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `lxml` as it is in most regards more efficient than stdlib `xml.ElementTree`.

You shall not attempt to parse the whole document as a whole as it is too large, but should approach the source document iteratively.

At `lxml` pages is [Event driven parsing](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing)

There are two options:

- `etree.iterparse`
- using custom parser, firing SAX-like events

I personally prefer the `etree.iterparse` as it gives you parsed elements in much more convenient way. But you must not forget to do the clean-up work on processed parts, otherwise you will not save any memory comparing to parsing the whole document at once.

**EDIT: added real example**

Example talks better then tons of theories. Here is my attempt:

```
from lxml import etree

# fname = "large.xml"  # 78 MB
fname = "verylarge.xml"  # 773 MB

toremove = []

for event, element in etree.iterparse(fname):
    if element.tag == "TableRow":
        if element.attrib["RowCount"] != "0":
            element.clear()
            # removing current element causes segmentation fault
            # element.getparent().remove(element)
            toremove.append(element)
    if element.tag == "TableData":
        for rowelm in toremove:
            element.remove(rowelm)
        toremove = []

# last processed element is the root one
with open("out.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(element))
```

To test the performance, I took your large sample file (73 MB), repeated inner part 10 times, got
773 MB large XML file and processed that.

The processing took 24 seconds (zenbook core i7 with 4 GB RAM) and resulting file was 4.7 MB large.

### Example explained

`iterparse` is by default providing only "end" events, fired when some element is completely parsed.

This solution uses the fact, that even with `iterparse`, the elements are kept in memory. This is used
in following places:

- during iterparse, not needed elements are cleared (`element.clear()`) and removed
  (`element.remove(rowelm)`). The `clear()` clears the inner content of the element, but the element
  still exists. The `remove()` works on parent element and removes the inner part from it.
- elements which are to be used are not removed and cleared, so we find them at the end present in
  the root element.
- finally, when all is processed, last processed `element` is the root one. It is still in memory,
  so I can write it as string to a file.

One has to be careful when to `remove()` the element. Trying to remove the element from parent at
the moment it was currently iterated element caused segmentation fault. For this reason the code
waits with `"TableRow"` element `remove()` until we complete parsing of parent `TableData` element.

Variable `toremove` is used to collect all `"TableRow"` elements and is used as soon as parent
`"TableData"` element is completely parsed. Note, that `remove()` works only on real element
parents, so we shall be sure we do it in proper time.

### Ideas for even larger files

For even larger files, this solution would be limited by size of resulting XML document as it is
kept in memory till the pruning of the source XML is completed.

For such scenarios, we would have to use writing out the output during parsing and getting rid of
all elements in memory, which are already processed. In practice, you would have to write out
"opening XML element" part (like `"<TaskReportSummary att="a" otheratt="bb"`) when "start" event
would appear, and write clossing XML element part `"/>"` at "end" event.

Comment: @siddhu619 Real working example added.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I have tried:

```
xmL = 'F:\\Reports\\Logs\\Result_TG1_V16.xml'


context = etree.iterparse(xmL,  events=("start", "end"),)
for event, element in context:
if element.tag == 'TasksReportNode':
    for child1 in element:
        for child2 in child1:
        if child2.get("RowCount") == "0":
            for child3 in child2:
            print(child3.tag, child3.text)
element.clear() # discard the element
del context
```

Now we have all the **RowCount** with value '0' and that can be added to parent, leaving all other siblings.

Comment: Your `iterparse` is registering both "start" and "end" events. For this reason you probably get empty list at `for child1 in element`, as these are not parsed yet at that moment. Note, that your attempts are better added into your question (unless you come to real working solution serving as an answer). People trying to answer your question can then easier see your effort.

Comment: If this isn't a solution you're happy with, you should add this to the question instead of adding it to an answer

Comment: @TejasPendse This solved my problem .

Comment: @JanVlcinsky  I have executed the above code and I am not getting empty list **for child1  in element**